# If the normal equation works, why do we need gradient descent?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, gradient-descent

Recently, I followed the open course CS229,
http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.pdf
This lecturer introduces an alternative approach to gradient descent that is called "Normal Equation" and the equation is as follows:

$$\theta=\left(X^{T} X\right)^{-1} X^{T} \vec{y}$$

The normal equation can directly compute the $\theta$.

If the normal equation works, why do we need gradient descent? What is the trade-off between these two methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That [normal equation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalEquation.html) is sometimes called the [closed-form solution](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Closed-FormSolution.html).

The short answer to your question is that the closed-form solution may be impractical or unavailable in certain cases or the iterative numerical method (such as gradient descent) may be more efficient (in terms of resources).

[This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/23132/82135) gives you more details and an example.